# Strange behaviour of the TransactionScope in C#

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

My application has been enabled  `transaction` scope. The below code has been used to activate the Scope, it was activated for one hour. However, It has been ended in 10 mins.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,TimeSpan.FromHours(1)))
{
   // my code goes here.
}
```

What is the strange behavior? why doesn't it live up to one hour of life time?

Comment: What's the connection timeout? What's the command timeout?

Comment: Connection time out is One hour. what is command time out ?

Comment: in which environment is this running? local, azure, ...?

Comment: Also, please check the value of TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionmanager.maximumtimeout.aspx

Comment: It's running in Windows Sever 2008 and application has been hosted in IIS

Answer (score 5):

You have to extend the default transaction timeout in your `app.config` (or `web.config`):

```
<configuration>
 <system.transactions>
  <defaultSettings timeout="00:03:00" />
 </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

You'll also have to change the configuration at the machine level, i.e. you'll have to edit the `machine.config` file too. The default maximum transaction timeout is [10 minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.machinesettingssection.maxtimeout.aspx) at the machine level.

For example, I've added at the end of my machine.config file the following XML:

```
  <system.transactions>
    <machineSettings maxTimeout="100.23:59:59" />
  </system.transactions>
```

The `machine.config` file is located in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[framework version]\Config` directory.

Comment: I could not find any documentation of these 10 minutes, do you have a link? Edit: Maybe this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.machinesettingssection.maxtimeout.aspx However, this thread suggests that you cannot override it on application level: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/584b8e81-f375-4c76-8cf0-a5310455a394

Comment: Unfortunately it couldn't solve my problem. I've updated both web.config as well as machine.config. but no hope it couldn't solve my problem still same problem has been exist.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Here's the one for the application level: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.defaultsettingssection.timeout.aspx The machinesettings should be updated in the machine.config.

Comment: @RameshMuthiah Have you tried restarting your machine? I'm guessing it's required after a machine.config update.

Comment: I didn't restarted my machine. I'm going to restart now and let update the status again. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

TransactionScope has a default maximum timeout of 10 minutes. If you create it with larger timeout it will silently reduce it to 10 mins anyway. It is a quite surprising behavior, but code does exactly that:

```
public TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption, TimeSpan scopeTimeout)
{
     ...
     timeout = TransactionManager.ValidateTimeout(scopeTimeout);
     ...
}
```

And ValidateTimeout reduces it to `TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout`

```
internal static TimeSpan ValidateTimeout(TimeSpan transactionTimeout)
{
    ...
    if (TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout != TimeSpan.Zero && (transactionTimeout > TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout || transactionTimeout == TimeSpan.Zero))
    {
        return TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;
    }
    return transactionTimeout;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the code? The `TimeSpan.FromHours(1)`, in particular?

Comment: Where is it documented that a `TransactionScope` will silently truncate the timout to 10 minutes? Not here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149852.aspx

Comment: Yes. alex your are absolutely right. It will silently ended at 10 mins. how can i improve the timeout ?

Comment: It will reduce it to TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout , which, by default, is 10 min. And @ken2k gave the answer on how to increase it.

Comment: @alex. Let me know one thing would be setting the transaction in machine config solve the issue ?

Comment: Thanks, this solved 'connection is closed' problem after 10 minutes long transaction.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing in the code inside the transaction?  Often, other timeouts come into play, like the SQL connection or command timeout, which can be shorter than the transaction timeout.